# WPF xaml and code

Tags: c#, wpf, progress

I have a problem with my progressbar in WPF. I want it into 2 colors (green when opartion went good and red when operation went wrong). I know that I should use xaml property LinearGradientBrush and GradientStop. I calculate my offset of progressbar in DivideImage.cs (not main class) so how can I get access to them? I have to set this offset in xaml file but I do not know how can I get access to these variables. Please, help.

Comment: If you want to change xaml properties from your code, then it is better to do this with binding. Or if you want to edit it in VS, there is a XAML tab on form editing

Comment: What "offset" are you talking about?

Comment: <GradientStop Offset=" "/>

Comment: So how can I bind this?

Comment: ="{Binding xxx}"

Comment: So the whole progress bar should become red if the calculation fails?
Maybe you should consider a DataTrigger binding on the error and changing the Foreground Property of the Progress Bar ?

Comment: I want to my all progressbar not become red if the calculation fails, i want to my progressbar changed only fragments when calculation fails.
For example i have 25 iterations to do. Errors will be in fivth and eleventh iteration. So my progressbar should will be red only in this parts, rest should be green.

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataTrigger Binding could do the trick:

```
    <ProgressBar Minimum="0"
                 Maximum="100"
                 Height="10"
                 Value="{Binding MyProgress}">
        <ProgressBar.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsError}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ProgressBar.Resources>
    </ProgressBar>
```

Your ViewModel could tell if there is an error via the Property `IsError`